# How to "absolute-ly" take from a number? (How to offset a number?)

Tags: gdscript

Essentially what I need to do is a - b, but I don't know what either will be and if a is positive then how can I take b from a in a "absolute" way?

What I mean is for example A = 10 and B = 5. Answer is obviously 5. If A was now -10, the answer is now -5. The answer leans towards 0 no matter what the numbers are. I heavily want to avoid using an if statement if I can.

My original idea was a - (b * (b / abs(b))). But b can be 0, and then div by 0 error occurs.

EDIT: A better way of saying it is I want to offset the result by an amount instead of math.

Comment: Maybe `sign(a) * (abs(a) - abs(b))`, with `sign` the sign function? 
Not sure what's the behavior you want when the absolute value of `b` exceeds that of `a` though. In any case the `sign` function may be handy.

Comment: Possibly your examples would be more clear if B values weren't a half plus/minus that of A. How about giving an expected results for A equal 10 or -10 and B=1? How about A=3 or A=-3 and B=10? And what if B was negative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So do I understand correctly that whatever the value of A, you want it to bias towards zero (based on the initial value of A) by the value of B?

So given: 
A=10 and B=5, the result will be 5.
A=-10 and B=5, the result will be -5.
A=-5 and B=-10, the result will be 5 (because it is offset by 10, towards zero from a starting point of -5).

Effectively the sign of B is immaterial because it specifies an offset towards zero in all cases.

What of the case where A=0 and B is non-zero? Is the result supposed to be undefined (because the appropriate direction of offset cannot be inferred), or is it supposed to be zero?

The formula for the latter case would be `(ABS(A) - ABS(B)) * SIGN(A))` (assuming that the sign function returns 0 when A is zero).

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, my brain decided to jump off a cliff while writing this because I actually meant I want the results that normal math already gives and I for some reason thought the bias to 0 was how math worked normally, thus my terrible description of the problem.

I'll probably end up using this formula in the future though so it isn't a waste.

Comment: @SS163, ah well! If you need any more help just say. It did seem like an unusual formula!